# Parse filenames with Space and ( ) in DOS batch

Tags: batch-file, dos

How can I run this batch script on filenames with space and "(" ")"?

```
:Start
@Echo off
Set _SourcePath=C:\tifs\*.tif
Set _OutputPath=C:\txts\
Set _Tesseract="C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
:Convert
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_Tesseract% %%A %_OutputPath%%%~nA
:End   
Set "_SourcePath="
Set "_OutputPath="
Set "_Tesseract="
```

Comment: FOR /F is not supported in DOS, I assume you really mean Windows NT batch file but tagging with DOS does not really help your situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1) You need some additional quotes.

2) You are using the wrong form of FOR. Your code is using the /F option with an unquoted IN() cluase. This attempts to read the contents of a file, which can't possibly work because your name includes a wildcard. I think you want a listing of .TIF files which is best done using the simple form of FOR (no /F option).

```
for %%A in (%_SourcePath%) do echo Converting "%%A"...&%_Tesseract% "%%A" "%_OutputPath%%%~nA"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to something like this:

```
:Start
@Echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set _SourcePath=C:\tifs\*.tif
Set _OutputPath=C:\txts\
Set "_Tesseract=C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
:Convert
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_Tesseract% "%%A" "%_OutputPath%%%~nA"
:End   
Set "_SourcePath="
Set "_OutputPath="
Set "_Tesseract="
```

Now, my answer might not work but I think it might give you enough hints to figure it out.